# Hello Getting parsing json file

Tags: json, parsing, python-3.5

I need some help here parsing a json data :

My json File contain this

```
{
  "message": "{\"gender\":\"MADAME\",\"Polo\":\"POTA\",\"last_name\":\"pato\",\"email\":\"pato.pota@mailler.com\",\"subject\":\"toto claim\",\"sub_subject\":\"Claim insurance car\",\"question\":\"claim for red car\",\"store\":\"claiming for incident\"}",
  "context": [

  ],
  "level": 200,
  "level_name": "INFO",
  "channel": "mailer",
  "datetime": {
    "date": "2016-09-19 11:00:26.795353",
    "timezone_type": 3,

  },
  "extra": [

  ]
}
```

### Python Code.

```
import os
import json


def Get_running_dir():

    path = os.getcwd()

file = path + "\json_data.txt"
print(file)

with open(file, 'r') as f:

    data = f.read()          

    data_json = json.loads(data)

    print(data_json)
    print(type(data_json))

Get_running_dir()
```

The issue is { print(type(data_json))} this is a dict right.

Once I call this  print(data_json['message']['gender'])

```
<class 'dict'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Extract_log.py", line 29, in <module>
Get_running_dir()
File "Extract_log.py", line 25, in Get_running_dir
print(data_json['message']['gender'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I need some help to parse this file please help me.

Thanking you in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I figured how to work with the json, this out today.

```
import os
import json


def Get_running_dir():

    path = os.getcwd()

file = path + "\json_data.txt"
print(file)

with open(file, 'r') as f:

    data = f.read()          

    data_json = json.loads(data)
    # My error was here:
    print(data_json['message']) # This convert to String.

    msg = json.loads(data_json['message']) # THIS CONVERT THE STRING TO #Dict.
#  this way i can access its keys.
#  Like this.

    print(msg['gender'] ,msg['first_name'], msg['last_name'])
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to describe your solution, as to help other people who stumble upon your question.